# Issue in using extremely huge Excel File with Formula in C#

Tags: c#, excel, aspose-cells

In my current project, Aspose has been used to work with Excel file (XLXS). This excel file has 4 worksheets. First two sheets are empty except they have first row which contain column names. These tab got data through code and other two contains tons of complex formula based on these inputs. Just imagine first two tab as inputs, third tab as complex calculation and last tab as output. Average size of file ranges from 26MB to 48MB. Below piece of code does most of the work. After this method, the file has been saved in some physical location too. output date saved in DB. This process working fine so far with above range, but when size exceeded beyound 100MB, it started throwing Out of Memory exception. Hardly once or twice, it able to complete the process in around 80 - 100 mins.

```
public void CaclulateM(DataSet dataModel)
        {
                 var workbook = this.ExcelModel.Workbook;
                 var ranges = ExcelModel.GetExcelModelRanges;
                 base.ImportInputsTo(workbook, ranges, dataModel);
                 workbook.CalculateFormula(false);
                 base.ExportOutputsTo(workbook, ranges, dataModel);
        }
```

I tried out some of the solution provided by Aspose, but failed.I tried other dlls too including Interop, ExcelLibrary, NPOI, but same result.

https://forum.aspose.com/t/aspose-cell-dll-issue-for-xslb-file/164440

Please help or let me know if you need any other input to suggest anything. I cannot provide you the excel file due to confidentiality.

Comment: Try also EasyXLS. https://www.easyxls.com/manual/tips-and-tricks/export-large-excel-file.html

Comment: It look like memory leakage issue not the ASPOS or NPOI issue. Use CLRProfiler or Perfmon to check if your Generation 1 or 2 has more memory allocation for  garbage collection than Generation 0.  you'll have to find out memory leaking methods/connection and handle it appropriately.

Comment: @kumarchandraketu - workbook.CalculateFormula(false);
 is Aspose inbuilt method which is taking most of the memory. Even When I open that XLXS file and put the input datas and hit calculate now, it is taking almost the same time. Is there still a scope of improvising memory utilization.  By the way, I also tried RecyclableMemoryStreamManager

Comment: @alex.pulver - I am not sure, if I can have DLL available in NuGet. If not, I cannot use that tool

Comment: Since ASPSO doesn't uses MS Excel dll internally so there can't be unmanaged resource memeory due to Excel.exe process. I'll suggest you to use most recent versionof ASPOS, where this issues may have addressed  and refer the documentation of ASPOS.

Comment: Please share one simplest Excel file which you could create manually. You can also share the screenshots. It should tell the relationship between your first two sheets with other sheets. We don't need your large Excel file, we just need your very simple Excel file telling the relationship of your first two sheets with other sheets. This will help us know the structure of your Excel file. ----- Regards Shakeel ---Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose